# Переадресация трафика с разных ПК на разные ВПН-интерфейсы

Tags: mikrotik

Настроил несколько ВПН-интерфейсов по l2tp на микротике, работает. Но сейчас хочу сделать так, чтобы с разных ПК трафик ходил на разные ВПН-интерфейсы, в зависимости от IP-адреса. Посоветуйте наиболее лаконичный вариант и как его реализовать.

Answer (score 0):

в роутах добавляешь 0.0.0.0 через l2tp-out1 таблица out1

в роуте рулес добавляешь

- dst=локалка lookup main
- src=ip1 lookup out1

аналогично для других: ip2->out2->l2tp-out2